# Splitting fitness and nutrition

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, nutrition

Many people ask here questions about nutrition that are not fully related to fitness but it's clear that nutrition is related topic.

It seems there is no other possibility where nutrition questions can be asked, or is it?

Would it be possible to create two SE sites from Fitness and nutrition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While its the whole point of Area51 to only launch sites that have sufficient experts. The problem I've always had with Nutrition is that we lacked the required experts to answer these questions authoritatively.

So a Nutrition site that would be cast off from Fitness, which in all honesty is not what's happening, would need to go back to Area51 and get sufficient followers to get back into beta again.

If the site were to launch with our current type of audience, it would be swamped by people wanting to hear they can drink Diet Coke all day long and that eating supplements is a great replacement for eating their veggies. Not the kind of expert discussions Stack Exchange is hoping to cater to.

So I think no, it won't be possible to create two sites.